# Find dimension and one basis of $W_1,W_2,W_1+W_2,W_1\cap W_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W_1=\operatorname{span}\{(1,-1,-3),(3,0,-3),(1,2,3),(4,5,6)\}$ and $W_2=\operatorname{span}\{(6,3,7),(0,0,11),(-4,-2,0)\}$. Find dimension and one basis of $W_1,W_2,W_1+W_2,W_1\cap W_2$.

$$       A= \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & -3 \\
        3 & 0 & -3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\sim \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow \operatorname{rank}(A)=2\Rightarrow \dim(W_1)=2$$

How to find one basis for $W_1$?

$$       B= \begin{bmatrix}
        6 & 3 & 7 \\
        0 & 0 & 11 \\
        -4 & -2 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\sim \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1/2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow \operatorname{rank}(B)=2\Rightarrow \dim(W_2)=2$$

How to find one basis for $W_2$?

For $W_1+W_2,$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & -3 \\
        3 & 0 & -3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
        6 & 3 & 7 \\
        0 & 0 & 11 \\
        -4 & -2 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\sim \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow \dim(W_1+W_2)=3$$

How to find one basis of $W_1+W_2$?

From previous, $\dim(W_1\cap W_2)=1$

How to find one basis of $W_1\cap W_2$?

Could someone show the procedure for finding at least one basis for either $W_1,W_2,W_1+W_2$ or $W_1\cap W_2$?

Comment: the basis for $W_1$ are the non-sero rows, that is, $W_1$ have dimension $2$. Same for the other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_1 + W_2$ you can take the non-zero rows as a basis of the vector spaces. To find the elements in the intersection it must be written as a linear combination of the basis of both vector spaces, so it reduces to solving the equation:

$$a(1,0,-1) + b(0,1,2) = c(1,\frac 12,0) + d(0,0,1)$$

Comment: $b=\frac{1}{2}a,c=a,d=0$. One basis of $W_1\cap W_2$ is $\{        a\begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        1/2  \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}: a\in\mathbb R\}$ If $\dim(W_1\cap W_2)>1$, how would we know be basis?

Comment: In a similar manner, but you instead of one free variable you will have more.

Answer (score 0):

Just thik it geometrically.You have made my answer easier by calculating the rank of each of the subspaces.Rank of W1 is 2 implies that W1 represents a plane in 3 dim. space.That spanning set which you have given...any two elements are independent...so you may take any two of them to form the basis. ie. {(1,-1,-3);(3,0,-3)} is a basis (look you may take the basis in 4C2 ways). From the similar idea you can find out the basis of W2.
Now dimension of W1+W2 is 3(as you calculated).Look both W1and W2 are subspace of R3(3 dimensional euclidean space).So you have the easiest answer!Just take your standard basis {(1,0,0);(0,1,0);(0,0,1)}.
Now look intersection of W1 and W1 has dimension 1 which represents a straight line.You are to find out those planes that represents W1 and W2 and obviously their intersecting part is that straight line.Just calculate it